# Trouble with Java Public Enum

Tags: java

I am attempting to simulate a BB84 protocol using Java programming language. Anyway, I am having some trouble with getting the complimentary/invert set of data from the result.

In my program, there is a total of 3 steps involved.

```
1. Generate 5 random binary number **check** 
---> exp: 10010 
2. Random bases to represent each bits (either rectilinear or diagonal) **check** 
---> exp: RECTILINEAR, RECTILINEAR, DIAGONAL, DIAGONAL, RECTILINEAR  
3. Complimentary bases (Invert bases used in second step) **not check** 
---> exp: DIAGONAL, DIAGONAL, RECTILINEAR, RECTILINEAR, DIAGONAL
```

This is my runnable program: [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_java_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMUTZlakhkWUFpRjg)

As you can see, I've attempted to write a class `Basis complimentary()` in Basis.java that will take in random basis generated and invert the bases used.

```
public enum Basis {
    RECTILINEAR,
    DIAGONAL;

    public static Basis random() {
        int i = (int)(Math.random()*2);
        if(i==0)
            return Basis.RECTILINEAR;
        else
            return Basis.DIAGONAL;
    }


    public static Basis complimentary() {

            if (Basis.random()==Basis.RECTILINEAR)
            {
                return Basis.DIAGONAL;
            }
            else
            {
                return Basis.RECTILINEAR;
            }
        }

}
```

But I notice it is generating random bases all over again and my third step does not seem to output the invert set used in the second step. Help is appreciated.

Edited:

So, in the FilterScheme2.java, i referenced FilterScheme1.java in the constructor like this.

```
public class FilterScheme2 extends AbstractScheme{
    private Filter[] filters;

    public FilterScheme2(int size) {
        super(size);

        filters = new Filter[size];

        FilterScheme1 f = new FilterScheme1(size);//reference to FilterScheme1.java

        for(int i=0;i<size;i++) {
             filters[i] = new Filter(filters[i].getBasis().complimentary()); //generate the second set of complimentary bases (rectilinear/diagonal)  
                }

    }
```

I tried to output `System.out.println(f.toString());` to make sure that I get the same data as FilterScheme1 but it seems like it generate random bases again. What could be the problem?

Comment: How are you calling these functions? Also in `complimentary` you are generating a new random value, not accessing any existing one

Comment: Your `random()` method returns each basis randomly... and so does `complimentary()`. Why would you expect it to give the exact opposite? Put it this way: suppose you roll a dice 10 times and record the results. You then roll the dice another 10 times and record "7-roll" each time. Would you expect those two sequences of numbers to be related? No - because you're *rolling the dice each time*.

Comment: please include the `main` withing the question as code and not as a link. The link might break, the text wont

Comment: ´complimentary()` should not be static. it should work like this: `Basis v = Basis.random(); System.out.printlin(v.complimentary());`

Comment: `new FilterScheme1(size)` will give you a _new_ instance of _random_ `Basis` instances. Instead, change the constructor signature to `public FilterScheme2(FilterScheme1 base, int size) { …` then `filters[i] = new Filter(base.getFilter(i).getBasis().complimentary())`

Comment: @Cael Consider taking this to [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) if you'd like feedback on the overall approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reference *what* exact instance you want the compliment of. This can be done by passing as argument, or by making `complimentary` non-static:

```
public static Basis complimentary(Basis subject) {
  if (subject == Basis.RECTILINEAR)
  {
    return Basis.DIAGONAL;
  }
  else
  {
    return Basis.RECTILINEAR;
  }
}
…
Basis.complimentary(Basis.DIAGONAL); // RECTILINEAR
```

Or

```
public Basis complimentary() {
  if (this == Basis.RECTILINEAR)
  {
    return Basis.DIAGONAL;
  }
  else
  {
    return Basis.RECTILINEAR;
  }
}
…
Basis.DIAGONAL.complimentary(); // RECTILINEAR
```

Comment: I've intentionally left the structure of the method body untouched as this is irrelevant for the overall approach.

Comment: I followed your method of removing the static from complimentary class. I tried to modified the FilterScheme2.java which has the line filters[i] = new Filter(Basis.random().complimentary()); but seems to be displaying random bases too. Not sure if I did correctly

Comment: Yes, every time you invoke `random()` you get a random! You want to to `filters[i] = new Filter(<the-Basis-instance-from-filters[i]>.complimentary())`

Comment: @Cael Consulting your codebase it apears to be `filters[i] = new Filter(filters[i].getBasis().complimentary())`

Comment: Thanks. weird tho it shows java.lang.NullPointerException when I try to run the line filters[i] = new Filter(filters[i].getBasis().complimentary()); Any idea why its not passing any value? Updated link on my post

Comment: Right, I wasn't paying attention. The `filters` array is empty so `filters[i].getBasis()` _will_ yield a NPE. `FilterScheme2` must have a reference to `FilterScheme1` in it's constructor in order to get the compliment for each `i`.

Comment: can u take a look at my edited post? Srry im quite new to Java